# PHP-Zend Framework getPost() returns null and select() function doesnt work

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm new to Zend and making my first big project. I am facing two problems:

The first one is that `getPost()` always returns NULL. I was trying different ways too but even `$_POST[]` but still returns NULL. Here's the code
form:

```
<?php 
class Application_Form_Add extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
        $this->setAction('b-add'); 
        $this->setMethod('post') ; 


        $name = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('name') ;
        $name->setRequired(true) ; 
        $name->setLabel('Podaj tytul') ;


        $sciezka = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('sciezka') ;
        $sciezka->setRequired(true) 
        ->setLabel('Podaj sciezke') ;


        $kom = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('kom') ;
        $kom->setRequired(false) 
        ->setLabel('Podaj komentarz') ;


        $sub = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('sub') ;
        $sub->setRequired(true) 
        ->setLabel('dodaj album') ;


        $this->addElements(array($name,$sciezka, $kom, $sub)) ;
    }
```

And b-add

```
public function bAddAction()
    {
        // action body
        if(isset($_POST['name'])) {

            $name = $this->getRequest()->getPost('name', null);
            $sciezka = $this->getRequest()->getPost('sciezka', null);
            $kom = $this->getRequest()->getPost('kom', null);

            require_once "C:/xampp/htdocs/projects/plyta/application/models/Database.php" ;

            $datab = new Application_Model_Database();

            $datab->add(array(
            [name] => $name,
            [sciezka] => $sciezka,
            )) ;

            //header('Location : index') ;*/
        }
}
```

The seccend error is that when I use `select()` the webpage is not found any more:

```
public function pokaz() {
    $db =new Application_Model_DbTable_Database() ;
    $select = $db->select();
    $select->from('pytania') ;
    $r = $select->query() ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following:

```
use Application_Model_Database; // put this above class declaration

 public function bAddAction()
    {   
     if ($this->request->isPost()) {
         $formData = $this->request->getPost();
         $datab = new Application_Model_Database();

                $datab->add(array(
                ['name'] => $formData['name'],
                ['sciezka'] => $formData['sciezka'],
                )) ;
}
}
```

There's a couple things I noticed, but one mistake in particular. Where you are declaring your array you haven't put in the ' or " around the name and sciezka.
Hope this helps.

```
$datab->add(array(
            [name] => $name,
            [sciezka] => $sciezka,
            )) ;
```